# Implementing jQuery Plugin Chosen not taking effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, jquery-chosen

I am new to javascript and jQuery, but I am trying to use the Chosen plugin. I have followed all the steps I can find, but it is not working. Here is what I have done so far.

index.blade.php:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="wim">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>WIM(afy)</title>

    <link href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/wimmain.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="bower_components/chosen/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/lodash/lodash.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-local-storage/dist/angular-local-storage.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/restangular/dist/restangular.min.js"></script>

    <script src = "js/app.js"></script>
    <script src = "js/services.js"></script>
    <script src = "js/controllers.js"></script>

    <style>

        li {
            padding-bottom: 8px;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body style="background-color: lightgray;">     
    <div ng-view></div>

    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/chosen/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".chosen-select").chosen();
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

I have included the stylesheet at the top, and included chosen.jquery.js after I included jQuery and before my script. The actual HTML page is displayed at the point where it says `<div ng-view></div>`.

Here's the html:

```
<select class="chosen-select" id="interests" multiple="true" ng-model="interests">
    <option value="Art">Art</option>
    <option value="Biking">Biking</option>
    <option value="Camping">Camping</option>
    <option value="Coffee">Coffee</option>
    <option value="Concerts">Concerts</option>
    <option value="Dining">Dining</option>
    <option value="Running">Running</option>
    <option value="Shopping">Shopping</option>
</select>
```

Right now it is just displaying the normal HTML 5 multiple select list where you have to hold shift or use ctrl to select multiple things.

[image: not working]

Do I need to move my code around differently? Can someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: `#` = ID-selector, `.` = class-selector, now review your html and js carefully

Comment: @empiric I edited the above question and am still getting the normal html multiple select

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your issue, but I have had to trigger an update on chosen before.  Try `$("#interests").trigger("update")`

Comment: changed to  
`<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#interests").trigger("update")
 });
</script>`

and no luck

Comment: Well I also just noticed that you're referring to `#chosen` but that doesn't seem to exist in your html.  Try `$("#interests").chosen()`

Comment: Ok, I may have misunderstood your question initially.  Are you trying to use [multiselect](http://loudev.com/)?  If so, I think you need that instead of chosen.

Comment: chosen has multiselect functionality